# Destroy a wcf thread

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I'm using multithreaded wcf maxConcurrentCalls = 10. By logging calls to my service I see that 10 different threads are executing in my service class and that they are reused in the following calls.

Can I tell WCF to destroy/delete a thread so it will create a new one on the next call?

This is because I have thread-static state that I sometimes want to be cleared (on unexpected exceptions). I am using the thread-static scope to gain performance.

Comment: Using ThreadStatic in scenarios where you don't control threads manually is bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF doesn't create new threads. It uses threads from a thread pool to service requests. So when a request begins it draws a thread from this pool to execute the request and after it finishes it returns the thread to the pool. The way that WCF uses threads underneath is an implementation detail that you should not rely on. You should never use Thread Static in ASP.NET/WCF to store state.

In ASP.NET you should use  `HttpContext.Items` and in WCF `OperationContext` to store some state that would be available through the entire request.

Here's a [good blog post](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/17/abstracting-request-state/) you may take a look at which illustrates a nice way to abstract this.

Comment: This is not a asp.net scenario

Comment: @Stig, yes, it is a WCF scenario. Similar rules: don't use thread static in a scenario where you don't have control over the threads. Use OperationContext as I suggested.

Comment: actually I am using Structuremap to provide instances in a thread-static scope.

Comment: @Stig, well, then you shouldn't. You should use request scope. This post could be useful: http://blog.mikeobrien.net/2010/01/creating-structuremap-lifecycle-for-wcf.html

Comment: great blog post I think I can use it. I could implement a thread-static scope lifecycle with an option to destroy it, right?

Comment: Per-thread scope is not supposed to be used in ASP.NET or WCF.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka please elaborate

Comment: @Stig: There is nothing to elaborate. Per-thread scope just internally uses ThreadStatic which should be used only if you have control over threads. It is not the case of ASP.NET or WCF where the engine uses thread pool and reuses its threads.